# Compare, Remove and Add files in a folder

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, sh

I have a folder (Folder A) in which I add pictures throughout a day.

Say, there's another folder (Folder B) in which there are pictures to upload.

I want to run a script that compares the files in Folder A and Folder B, removes the common files from Folder B and adds not common files to Folder B. I have zilch experience with shell scripting and thought of asking around here.

Thanks!

Comment: SO is here to help with code you wrote but SO is not here to write code for you nor give you a tutorial on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The below iterates over the files of `DIR_A`. Any file also found in `DIR_B` (ie, a "common file") is removed from `DIR_B`. Any file not found in `DIR_B` (ie, a "not common file") is added to `DIR_B`.

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR_A="~/pics"
DIR_B="~/uploads"

for pic in `ls $DIR_A`; do
    if [ -e "$DIR_B/$pic" ]; then
        rm $DIR_B/$pic
    else
        cp $DIR_A/$pic $DIR_B/$pic
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry - This looks like it'll work but I have a faint idea about how to use this. Is this supposed to be saved as `.sh` file? I tried to save it as `backup.sh` it on `Rpi` and run `./backup.sh`. It gives me a command not found error.

On Mac, I tried `sh backup.sh` and `pics: No such file or directory`, whereas I did create `pics` and `upload` directories both and checked their paths.

Comment: yes, save it as a `.sh` file. Once you do, make it executable with `chmod +x backup.sh`. You will then be able to run it with `./backup.sh`. You'll notice I added the shebang to the top of the file; that tells your shell what binary should be used to run the file (in this case, sh; you could, for example, change it to bash).

Comment: Still seems to give me `ls: cannot access "~/pics": No such file or directory` on running the `.sh` script both in mac and raspberry.

Comment: I used that as a stand-in for whatever your actual picture directory is. Also, when in doubt, use an absolute path (`/home/myname/pics` vs `~/pics`).

Comment: Yeah. Not sure what's going on. I think it's a permissions issue with the way script is used. I tried chmod 777 on all but still didn't work. Tried different folders, asbolute paths, different computer but the same result.

I did replace pics with my own directory names and also tried the absolute path. ls: cannot access "/home/pi/folder1": no such file or directory is the current error as well